# twemoji not converting the strings

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use twemoji (https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) to convert unicode emoji characters.

I have a very simple page:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title></title>
  <script src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/twemoji.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <span>
 What a cool string \ud83c\udf88\ud83c\ud83c\udf88\ud83c\ud83c\udf88\ud83c</span>
</body>

</html>
```

According to the documentation when you run

```
twemoji.parse(document.body)
```

it should run through the page and replace all the unicode characters into  tags.
That is not happening BUT if you take that string and put it directly into the function so

```
twemoji.parse("What a cool string \ud83c\udf88\ud83c\ud83c\udf88\ud83c\ud83c\udf88\ud83c");
```

and run it in the console in Chrome it does indeed show converted string.

```
What a cool string <img class="emoji" draggable="false" alt="" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f388.png"><img class="emoji" draggable="false" alt="" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f388.png"><img class="emoji" draggable="false" alt="" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f388.png">
```

The data comes from the database and it's been inputed using an iOS app.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a different notation when you want to write these characters in html:

`&#127880;`=>🎈 or `&#x1f388;`=>🎈

see: http://www.charbase.com/1f388-unicode-balloon

```js
twemoji.parse(document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/twemoji.min.js"></script>
<span>
 What a cool string  &#127880; &#x1f388;  
</span>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can convert those  with javascript ?

Comment: What do you want to do with javascript?

Comment: Convert those unicode characters to the notation you mentioned.

Comment: you may use a regexp to find such sequences and replace them with the HTML-notation(athough and don't see any use-case)

Comment: The string I get comes from the DB directly, so to use that other notation I need to convert "\ud83c\udf88" to &#127880; for twemoji to work. My question is how do I do that ?

Comment: nvm I solved it converting them in the backend. thanks a lot!